# Waiting on 1 test

Tags: jestjs

I have the following test

// **tests**/CheckboxWithLabel-test.js

```
jest.dontMock('../test.js');
describe('CheckboxWithLabel', function() {
  it('changes the text after click', function() {
    var React = require('react/addons');
    var CheckboxWithLabel = require('../test.js');
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

    // Render a checkbox with label in the document
    var checkbox = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
    );

    // Verify that it's Off by default
    var label = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
      checkbox, 'label');
    expect(label.getDOMNode().textContent).toEqual('Off');

    // Simulate a click and verify that it is now On
    var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(
      checkbox, 'input');
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
    expect(label.getDOMNode().textContent).toEqual('On');
  });
});
```

when I try to run it though using jest, I get the following error: Waiting on 1 test

I run npm test

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the version of Node you were using. Your problem could be because you are using a newer version of Node and Jest works with version 0.10.0. This is an open issue on Github (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/243)

To downgrade your version of node, use the n package as follows:

```
npm install -g n   # Install n globally
n 0.10             # Installing the correct version of node
```

This can result in some weird problems with your current packages, so delete your node_modules folder and perform a clean install.